# Is there a way to get a shadertorgb output into geometry nodes? (Shading Stylized brush strokes)

Tags: geometry-nodes, shaders, eevee-render-engine, toon-shading, npr

i'm trying to recreate a "3D painting effect" with geometry nodes. The goal is to make any shaded mesh turn into this kind of style : https://www.instagram.com/p/Ba4CtFXhnzI/

I've managed to get some work done, here is my progress so far :

[image: Suzanne in the current 3D paint look]

This looks alright with sun lights, but the painterly look is ruined when using point lights because gradients begin appearing in the strokes :

[image: point light shading on the effect]

one way to change that would be to shade the stroke instances with a shader to rgb node and to only keep the value of one vertex to shade the entire instance, but i'm not sure this is even possible considering attribute statistic doesn't exist in shader nodes. If there was a way to get the shader to rgb output into geonodes then it would be much easier.

Here are my nodes :

Geometry nodes setup [image: geometry nodes setup]

Shader nodes [image: shader nodes]

Thanks in advance

Here is my file: [image]

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, I added it to my post !